# 画像の中にあるドットを横に連結させたい

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, pillow

画像の中にある黒いドットを横に連結させたいです。

cv2 のcontoursで輪郭を検出し、ユークリッド距離を用いて、取得した輪郭座標間の間隔が最大になるように四点の座標を作成しました。その後、黒いドット間の白いスペースをcv2.fillPoly で埋めてみましたが、画像の中心部がうまく処理できません。
もしよろしければ、ご教授いただけないでしょうか？

画像の生成方法は以下の通りです。

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

# 画像の設定
width, height = 1000, 1000
dot_size = 20
dot_interval = 20
shift_right = 20

# 画像の生成
image = Image.new("RGB", (width, height), "white")
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)

# ドットの描写
for i in range(shift_right, width, dot_size + dot_interval):
    for j in range(0, height, dot_size + dot_interval):
        draw.rectangle([i, j, i + dot_size, j + dot_size], fill="black")

# 画像の保存
image.save("shifted_square_dot_pattern.png")


import cv2
import numpy as np

# 画像のロード
image = cv2.imread("shifted_square_dot_pattern.png", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
rows, cols = image.shape

# マッピング設定
def gaussian_skew_mapping(x, y, amplitude, sigma):
    return amplitude * np.exp(-((y - rows // 2) ** 2) / (2 * sigma ** 2))

# 変形行列
transformation_matrix = np.float32([[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]])
skewed_image = np.zeros_like(image)

for y in range(rows):
    for x in range(cols):
        deformation = int(gaussian_skew_mapping(x, y, 20, 100))
        new_x = x + deformation
        if 0 <= new_x < cols:
            skewed_image[y, new_x] = image[y, x]

# 変形画像の保存
cv2.imwrite("gaussian_skewed_shifted_square_dot_pattern.png", skewed_image)
```

画像の処理は以下の通りです

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
img_h = cv2.imread("gaussian_skewed_shifted_square_dot_pattern.png")
gray_h = cv2.cvtColor(img_h, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
# 2値化処理
# 画像の特徴的な部分、関心のある部分を抽出するように変換する処理
threshold=130
ret, gray_h_thresh = cv2.threshold(gray_h,threshold,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
plt.imshow(gray_h_thresh)
#輪郭抽出
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(gray_h_thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
#輪郭の個数を表示
print(len(contours))

#左のドットではないスペースを削除
count =0
areas = []
list_contours = list(contours)
for i in range(len(contours)):
    area = cv2.contourArea(contours[i], True)
    areas.append(area)
   
    if area < -500:
        print(count)
        del list_contours[i]
    count+=1

#contours のサイズを2 x 4 に成形、ユークリッド距離を用いて近い座標を削除
for i in range(len(trimed_list_contours)):
    if not trimed_list_contours[i].shape[0] ==4:
        sq_index =[]
        for j in range(trimed_list_contours[i].shape[0]-1):
            euclidean_distance = np.sqrt(sum(sum((trimed_list_contours[i][j]-trimed_list_contours[i][j+1])**2)))
            sq_index.append(euclidean_distance)
    
        for k in range(trimed_list_contours[i].shape[0]-4):
            argmin = np.argmin(sq_index)
            trimed_list_contours[i] =np.delete(trimed_list_contours[i],argmin,0)
            sq_index = np.delete(sq_index,argmin,0)

#平行にドットをつなげる
count = 0
copy_gray_h=gray_h.copy()
#for i in range(0,26):
for i in range(len(trimed_list_contours)):
    count+=1
    if count == 25:
        count =0
        
        continue
    else:
        
        # Assuming you have a list or tuple of points from OpenCV, for example:
        opencv_points = [trimed_list_contours[i][0][0], trimed_list_contours[i][1][0], trimed_list_contours[i+1][2][0],trimed_list_contours[i+1][3][0]]

       
        opencv_points =np.vstack(opencv_points)
        cv2.fillPoly(copy_gray_h, [opencv_points], (0, 0, 0))
        
plt.imshow(copy_gray_h)
plt.show()
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 実現したいけれど上手くいかなかったプログラムは、提示されたソースコードのどの部分に当たるでしょうか？ 今書かれていなければそれも提示してみてください。あとどのような画像が得られれば良いか、今得られている画像はどんなもので何処がおかしいか、といったことを画像の一部を手作業で加工してでも提示すると助言や回答が付きやすいと思われます。こちらのヘルプ記事を参考にブラッシュアップしてみてください。[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

**[自己解決]**
目的の画像をドットのピクセル分だけ下にシフトし、元画像と合成することで疑似的に解決しました。

修正コード

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
img_h = cv2.imread("gaussian_skewed_shifted_square_dot_pattern.png")
gray_h = cv2.cvtColor(img_h, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
inv_im_gray_h = cv2.bitwise_not(gray_h)

dot_pixel_size =20


# 横方向にドットのピクセルサイズ分だけずらす
rows, cols, = inv_im_gray_h.shape
shifted_image = np.zeros_like(inv_im_gray_h)
shifted_image[:, dot_pixel_size:] = inv_im_gray_h[:, :-dot_pixel_size]
shifted_image[:,:dot_pixel_size]= 255

#画像の合成
merged_image = inv_im_gray_h+shifted_image
plt.imshow(merged_image, cmap = "Greys")
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]